# android - Dagger 2 won't inject into specific service

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dagger-2

I want to inject `SharedPPrefrences` object into different services and activities. I have this code:

**Application Module:**

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private Application mApp;
    public ApplicationModule(Application app) {
        mApp = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPrefs() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mApp);
    }
}
```

**Application Component:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(HealthCheckerApplication app);
    void inject(HomeActivity activity);
    void inject(Service activity);
    void inject(TestService activity);
    void inject(HealthService activity);
}
```

For some weird reason, the compiler gives me an compilation error **only** about the `HealthService` -

> HealthService cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or
>   from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members
>   injection but cannot be implicitly provided.

I cant understand for the life of me what's the difference between the services.

**Test Service:**

```
public class TestService extends Service  {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Health Service:**

```
public class HealthService extends Service {

    @Inject
    public NotificationCreator notificationCreator;

    @Inject
    public CallTooLongAlarm callTooLongAlarm;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        showToast("onCreate");
        ServiceComponent serviceComponent = DaggerServiceComponent.builder().serviceModule(new ServiceModule(this)).build();
        serviceComponent.injectService(this);

        notificationDataFactory = serviceComponent.provideFactory();
    }
}
```

**The only difference is** - I have a `ServiceModule` and `ServiceComponent` that help the `HealthService` inject himself into the constructors of `CallTooLongAlarm`, for example, but why is that a problem??

Comment: You should include the code where you either have `@Inject HealthService` or `@Inject MyConstructor(HealthService ...)`. The error says that *you* want the class injected somewhere but don't *provide* it&mdash;It can not be created by dagger and is not in any of the modules of the component, ...

Comment: I highly recommend you play around with dagger, just create a test project, some components, modules, and classes, try injecting and creating stuff until you get the hang of it. Also you should just read some tutorials and guides, check out some github samples...

Comment: Also, take note of the _location_ of the error message.  The element to which it is applied should give you a place to look for where your `HealthService` is being requested.